# Use google translate on only the body content, and not the navigation

Tags: html, google-translate

I want to incorporate the google translate snippet of code, but realized it totally messes up my layout as it translates my navigation dropdown menus. Can I only target areas with certain `<div>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how well it would work but you could have each drop down item be an image with the text. That would prevent translation

Comment: i guess that's the only way without having to pay for the translate api?

Comment: Im not sure but it's more of a workaround than a solution. I think without the api it would translate the entire text but with the api you may be able to select a specific div element

Answer (score 1):

You can use `class="notranslate"` on any HTML section you do not want to translate. So you could try and wrap a div around your whole navigation with that.

There is also a meta header meta name="google" value="notranslate" which stops the whole page from being translated.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a javascript function that generates the meny item text? so that each letter is encapsulated with html-tags, wouldn't that prevent Google Translate trying to translate the text?